# PHPActiveRecord allow_blank, allow_null not working on validations

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I have the following validator function.

```
static $validates_size_of = array(
        array('contactfirstname'    , 'within' => array(1,50),  'allow_null' => true),
        array('contactlastname'     , 'within' => array(1,50),  'allow_null' => true),
        array('contactemail'        , 'within' => array(5,255), 'allow_null' => true), //A@A.A ~ smallest possible email is 5 characters.
        array('companyemail'        , 'within' => array(5,255), 'allow_null' => true, 'allow_blank' => true), //A@A.A ~ smallest possible email is 5 characters.
        array('companyname'         , 'within' => array(1,75),  'allow_null' => true),
        array('contactphonenumber'  , 'within' => array(10,20), 'allow_null' => true),
        array('companyphonenumber'  , 'allow_null' => true, 'allow_blank' => true, 'within' => array(10,20)),
        array('address'             , 'within' => array(1,120))
    );
```

For companyphonenumber, I want to restrict the characters to within 10 to 20 but I also want to allow there to be a blank string or null if nothing was entered.  If something was entered however, then it should do the 10 to 20 characters long validation check.

This does not work however.  **Instead the within validation seems to still trigger when the item is blank or null**.  Am I doing something wrong, or does PHPActiveRecord have a bug here?

Comment: Try removing the `allow_null` key? Isn't it the same as blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns it this actually DOES work correctly, I just made a stupid error.  My apologies.  Ignore this question.